# Triple boot win7,Ubuntu,Kali

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation

I am running window7 and Ubuntu 13.10 together.

I'd like to also have Kali linux installed.Despite I did the installation of both OS , I am not a veteran in this subject , I dont know where to start on and if it is possible with a total HD of 250gb

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With currently five OSes installed on my 100GB hard drive, I can confirm that it is indeed possible to have more than a dual-boot.

You'll have to take some space from either Ubuntu or Windows to install kali.

I won't elaborate much, since it's explained well in the kali linux documentation: http://docs.kali.org/installation/dual-boot-kali-with-windows

As a side note, kali will install a new bootloader, which will replace Ubuntu's. While this isn't nessecarily bad, if you want ubuntu's classy purple GRUB, you may want to look up how to use `grub-install`.

Just a hint: search. There's a lot of documentation out there.

Comment: Hey thanks , I'll take a look at it. And thanks for the other informations , now I feel more comfortable.

Comment: Just have an ubuntu cd or usb in case things go wrong. As long as you don't delete or otherwise damage your current partitions, you will be able to recover your PC ;)

Comment: I did it. I followed the instruction in kali docs and some other website.Wasn't very easy , but now I have all three os working fine. Thanks for the help!