# Do I have to uninstall Lubuntu when installing other Linux distros

Tags: lubuntu, uninstall

I have a dual boot Lubuntu/windows 7 computer, but I want to installing new Linux, in this case Kali Linux from USB. I would like if my Lubuntu git purged, so do I just go in win and format the Lubuntu partition or can I install it just on top of my Lubuntu?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Triple boot win7,Ubuntu,Kali](http://askubuntu.com/questions/437836/triple-boot-win7-ubuntu-kali) and [Triple boot Ubuntu 13.10 with Windows 7 and Kali Linux](http://askubuntu.com/questions/407237/triple-boot-ubuntu-13-10-with-windows-7-and-kali-linux)

Answer (score 1):

You can install any number of OS's and Versions as long as your install them on their own separate partition.

When you install or update Grub, it'll scan all the attached drives for installed Operating systems detected and add them to the boot menu.  Then when you boot you can choose which Operation system for that session.

The different OS's will be independent of the others.

If you purge one Operation system (i.e. delete the files of that partition or delete that partition), the other partitions and the Operating Systems install on them will remain intact.